# Symfony2 form entity processing

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a User entity that has an ArrayCollection of Subscriptions. I have these setters and getters.

```
public function addSubscription(\Doge\WowBundle\Entity\Subscription $subscription)
{
    $this->subscriptions[] = $subscription;
    return $this;
}

public function removeSubscription(\Doge\WowBundle\Entity\Subscription $subscription)
{
    $this->subscriptions->removeElement($subscription);
}

public function getSubscriptions()
{
    return $this->subscriptions;
}
```

There is another entity called Plan. A Subscription is basically the intermediate entity between User and Plan, except it holds an extra field so it is necessary to be a dedicated entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="subscriptions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Plan", inversedBy="subscriptions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="plan_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $plan;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
protected $nextDue;
```

Otherwise, it would just be a many-to-many relationship with an automatic intermediate table generated.

Now in the User registration form, a user can choose between plans available in the Plans table with this code in the FormBuilder

```
$builder->add('subscriptions', 'entity', array('class' => 'DogeWowBundle:Plan'))
```

How can I create a new Subscription object given the Plan object? Would I do so in the controller? Use a datatransformer? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options, the first is that you have a form that contains a form.  One form is mapped to your user and the second is mapped to your subscription.  So basically in your user form you would have

```
$builder->add('subscriptions', new SubscriptionsType())
```

and within that SubscriptionsType you would have your entity for plans like:

```
$builder->add('plan', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'DogeWowBundle:Plan',
    'property' => 'plan_name',
));
```

this way your subscriptions will be auto generated and updated as necessary.

You could also use a data transformer, but i personally like using forms within forms.

Comment: The remaining problem is "Neither the property "subscriptions" nor one of the methods "setSubscriptions()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class". How do I invoke the addSubscription function, seeing as there can be more than one?

Comment: Secondly, how do the other fields in the subscription get set programatically not through the form?

Comment: assuming you have a registration form mapped to a user,
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $user);

whatever subscriptions the user already has will be selected already when the form is rendered.  then when handleRequest is called it sets all data from the form to the entity so you would have to implement setSubscriptions() for the first method to work.